# ASP.NET Core JWT Token not working via HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms

I'm new to JWT authentication and I've configured my ASP.NET Core 3 API for token authentication using the tutorial here:

https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/

I've added the `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller, and using Postman I can login and get a token, and use the token via Postman to retrieve the data from the controller - all works as expected to here.

My issue is when I login using the C# `HttpClient` via a Xamarin app, and then I use the the token that is sent back I get a 401 error accessing the controller either via Postman or `HttpClient`.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var model = new JwtLoginModel()
            {
                Email = email,
                Password = password,
                RememberMe = false
            };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);
var response = await client.PostAsync(Constants.BaseApiAddress + "api/Login", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
var accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("token");
```

Using the returned `accessToken` via Postman (and `HttpClient`), both return a 401 error.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post an example where you compare the output when authenticating (getting the token) via Postman and via HttpClient (I'm thinking about what `content` looks like)?

Comment: This is the code for getting the token I assume. Can you share the code where you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help

In the end I decided it was easier to go with Identity Server 4 implementation which is working perfectly